# Hbase error.. !!not able to create table in hbase

Tags: hbase, hdfs

I am not able to work with `hbase shell`. when i try to list databases in hbase 
list databases i am getting below error please help!! and even not able to create table

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hbase shell
16/08/02 08:51:57 WARN conf.Configuration: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.94.6-cdh4.3.0, rUnknown, Mon May 27 20:22:05 PDT 2013

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                           
16/08/02 08:52:45 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
16/08/02 08:52:46 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
16/08/02 08:52:47 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
16/08/02 08:52:49 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
16/08/02 08:52:51 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
16/08/02 08:52:55 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
16/08/02 08:52:59 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times

Here is some help for this command:
List all tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
be used to filter the output. Examples:
```

Comment: maybe you should check ```hbase-site.xml``` first and paste the content if you can't figure out the reason then.

Comment: anyways I have got solution for this.. coz Hbase Master services has stopped and i have restarted it.. Thank you